# Even though the domain fails to save the render view page code doesn't load?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I am puzzled why editdonation view page is not rendered since don.save() fails because in the domain if customDonationMin is greater than customDonationMax then validation error happens. I have pasted below the custom validator for your reference.

```
customDonationMax nullable: true, min: BigDecimal.ZERO, validator: { BigDecimal max, EventDonation obj ->
    if (max != null && obj.customDonationMin > max){
        return 'donation.min.max.error'
    }
}
```

The following is the updatedonation method. In the params i purposely set the customDonationMin greater than customDonationMax to fail the don.save()

```
def updatedonation(Long id){
    def ev = CompositeEvent.get(id)

    myAclService.hasWritePermission(ev.id, CompositeEvent)

    //Make sure the question that we are editing exists
    List<EventDonationCompositeEvent> donation_comp_event = EventDonationCompositeEvent.createCriteria().list(){
        eq('event', ev);
    }

    def don = donation_comp_event[0].donation

    List<String> whiteList = ['title', 'body', 'customDonationMin', 'customDonationMax']
    bindData(don, params, ['include': whiteList])

    //Now we save the donation

    if (!don.save()) {
        don.errors.each {       
            //here this render doesnt work instead the the below code executes redirect(controller: "compositeEvent", action: "home", id: id) 
            render(view: "editdonation", model: [id:id, donation:don])
            return  
        }
    }

    flash.message = "Donation setup successful!!"
    redirect(controller: "compositeEvent", action: "home", id: id)
    return
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you shouldn't need the `return` keywords after a `render` or `redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when i alter the above code as follows then the problem is solved.

```
 if (!don.save()) {

                //here this render doesnt work instead the the below code executes redirect(controller: "compositeEvent", action: "home", id: id) 

                render(view: "editdonation", model: [id:id, donation:don])
                return

        }
```